# Get the TimeValue From SQL Server DMZMGMT SQL server database in Unix and then send an email to users about elapsed time

Tags: sql, sql-server, email, unix

I have this query in SQL server , It yields time difference value between two steps.
I need to send an email via UNIX with the time difference value.

So I need to do the following steps which I am not aware of:

1. Connect Unix to SQL server to yield time difference value.
2. Send an email with time difference value.

Query:

```
select  Audit1.Time_  Time_Full_Calc , Audit2.Time_  Time_Step2_Calc  ,Cast(Audit2.Time  -  Audit1.Time  As Time ) As TimeDifferencefrom Schema.dbo.Table Audit1 inner join Schema.dbo.Table Audit2on CAST(Audit1.Time AS date) = CAST(Audit2.Time AS date)where CAST(getdate() AS date) = CAST(Audit2.Time AS date)and  CAST(getdate() AS date) = CAST(Audit1.Time AS date)
```

Comment: No , I want to send email via unix by getting the time value from SQL server

Answer (score 0):

```
sqlplus -s user/password@dbname <<EOF
set feedback off trimspool on 
spool file_name.txt;
select * from table_name;
spool off;
exit;
EOF


(uuencode file_name.txt file_name.txt )| mailx -s "subject XXXXX" user@mail.com
```

In detail here https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/159430-executing-sql-query-sending-mail.html

Comment: This is not working. I an not able to connect my SQL database

Comment: "not working" doesn't mean anything. Please post the actual error